# Change element style in EJS after POST action in Node - Express

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, ejs

I have a form page that should show a Success Alert (Boostrap) after a user fills out the form and hit the Submit button.

```
<form class="well form-horizontal" action="/contact" method="post"  id="contact_form">

... (input fields here)

<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message"> Success 
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly. 
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" > Submit <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

By default, in my CSS:

```
#success_message { display: none; }
```

How do I change the display property to not `none` (block, inline, inline-block) so that the success alert message appears, after the POST action in Node-Express ?

```
var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

    const data = {
        fname: req.body.name,
        lname: req.body.lname,
        ...
        comment: req.body.comment
    }

    // insert data using SQL/MongoDB library
    // refresh same page if success, the input elements cleared
    // and show the success alert or fail alert div in rendered HTML

        res.render('contact', {  
            fname :     ''
            lname :     ''
            ...
            comment : ''
        });

});
```

Is it possible to do this without jQuery? I prefer not to use jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1:**

First in the GET request add a `success` property to render. something like

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
...
...
    res.render('contact', {
        fname: '',               
        ........
        success: false
    });
});
```

and in POST, only after validating

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    ...
    ...
        res.render('contact', {
            fname: '',               
            ........
            success: true
        });
    });
```

In your ejs file you can do something like

```
<% if (success) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="success_message"> Success 
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly. 
    </div>
<% } %>
```

The Above method can also be used for errors.

**Method 2:**

Changing CSS are a bit too complicated, you can change classes or ids  instead. (always change classes, instead of ids)

```
#id1 {
... 
}

#id2 {
...
}
```

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id=<%= success ? "id1" : "id2" %>> Success 
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" ></i> Thanks for contacting us, we will get back to you shortly. 
</div>
```